# Iterating through one map and one multimap and printing the vlaue of common keys

Tags: c++

I've got one multimap: `mm1` and a map: `mm2`. The size of `mm1` is *usually* expected to be smaller than `mm2`. So I begin by iterating through `mm1`, and for each key in `mm1` that also exists in `mm2`, will print the values of them. e.g. in the following example, first I come up with 2 in `mm1`, which also exists in `mm2`; therefor I print "aa" and "bb" from `mm1` and "b" from `mm2`. If we encounter any key in `mm1` that cannot be found in `mm2`, the whole process will be stopped. Example:

(in each pair, number is key, string is value)

mm1:

> 2, "aa"
>   2, "bb"
>   4, "cc"
>   4, "dd"
>   5, "ee"

mm2:

> 1, "a"
>   2, "b"
>   3, "c"
>   4, "d"
>   6, "e"

output should be:

> aa
>   bb
>   b
>   cc
>   dd
>   d

For the following input, 4 is not found in the second map and therefore we stop printing values after 2 (even though 5 exists in both of them, it's not printed).

mm1:

> 2, "aa"
>   2, "bb"
>   4, "cc"
>   4, "dd"
>   5, "ee"

mm2:

> 1, "a"
>   2, "b"
>   3, "c"
>   5, "d"

output should be:

> aa
>   bb
>   b

And here is my code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    multimap<int,string> mm1;
    mm1.insert(make_pair(2, "aa"));
    mm1.insert(make_pair(2, "bb"));
    mm1.insert(make_pair(4, "cc"));
    mm1.insert(make_pair(4, "dd"));
    mm1.insert(make_pair(5, "ee"));

    map<int,string> mm2;
    mm2.insert(make_pair(1, "a"));
    mm2.insert(make_pair(2, "b"));
    mm2.insert(make_pair(3, "c"));
    mm2.insert(make_pair(4, "d"));
    mm2.insert(make_pair(5, "e"));

    typedef multimap<int,string>::iterator Iter;

    pair<Iter, Iter> range1(mm1.begin(), mm1.begin());
    Iter next1 = mm1.begin();
    map<int,string>::iterator next2 = mm2.begin();

    range1 = mm1.equal_range(next1->first);
    while (!(range1.first == mm1.end() && range1.second == mm1.end()))
    {
        next2 = mm2.find(next1->first); 
        if(next2 == mm2.end()) break;
        for (Iter itr = range1.first;itr!=range1.second;itr++)
        {
            cout << itr->second << endl;
        }
        cout << next2->second << endl;
        next1 = range1.second;
        next2++;
        if(next1 == mm1.end() || next2 == mm2.end())
            break;
        range1 = mm1.equal_range(next1->first);      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My intention was to iterate over each map only once. Any advice on improving the performance and size of this program would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. The English description does not seem to match the first example. The key "aa" in mm1 is not in mm2 so why is it in the expected output?

Comment: @LokiAstari "aa" is not a key, it's a value. The numbers are keys.

Comment: @LokiAstari Updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Sorry. Misread that. Totally my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple variation on the classic 'find common entries in 2 sorted lists' will do:

```
void printIntersection(multimap<int,string> mm1, map<int,string> mm2)
{
    map<int,string>::iterator iter1 = mm1.begin(), iter2 = mm2.begin();
    while (iter1 != mm1.end() && iter2 != mm2.end()) {
       if (iter1->first < iter2->first)
           iter1++;
       else if (iter1->first > iter2->first)
           iter2++;
       else {   // equal keys, print values
           while (iter1 != mm1.end() && iter1->first == iter2->first)
              cout << iter1++->second << endl;
           cout << iter2++->second << endl;   // unique map key, no need to loop
       }   // else
    }   // while
}
```

Comment: Upon reaching a key in `mm1` which is not available in `mm2`, the iteration should stop.

Comment: so replace `iter1++` with `return`

Answer (score 1):

You can merge both maps to a "list". That should give you O(n) complexity solution where n is a total number of elements in both maps.
map elements are sorted from lower to higher, so simple iteration would yield an ordered list.
To merge maps, you need to iterate both of the maps, instead of insertion to a list, you can just output values to the screen.

Comment: There is no need to merge the two maps. It does not make anything more efficient either. Even if I merge the two, there will be no way to know which keys have been available in both maps. Please read the question again.

Comment: As I've noted earlier, you do not have to create the list, but output values to the screen.
Once you hit a condition when the current value does not exist in the second map, you stop processing.
This way your code would visit each maps' element only once.

Comment: Isn't this what I have already done in my code? I am iterating only once.

Comment: `mm2.find` does a binary search with O(log n) complexity, so strictly speaking your are iterating more than once on mm2

Comment: You are right, `mm2.find` is always searching from the first element which is not necessary. Thank you